# Remove TFS process template customizatons

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, build-process-template

I'm trying to migrate from our on-premise TFS (2013.2) to Visual Studio Online (VSO).
One of the requirements from VSO is that you cannot use customized process templates.

My predecessor added few fields to few work item types wich I now have to remove, I don't care if I lose the data in those fields, just keep the standard ones.

I've tried few suggested methods but I'm not familiar enough with TFS to understand what I am doing :)

How can I remove those customizations?

I'm using OpsHub and following this guide: http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/migrate-team-projects-vs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a few things...

1) identify your process template

User Story = MSF for Agile
Requirement = MSF for CMMI
Product Backlog Item = Scrum

2) Connect to VSO and download the relevant process template.

3) Use "witadmin.exe" to upload the defaults for Work Item Types, Categories, and Process

You should then be on a comparable template.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using OpsHub Migration Utility. During the Validation process it will show you the list of mismatches.

For the validation to succeed, you will have to delete/destory those fields. (Warning : You will lose all the historic data for that field)

For deleting the field, you can use the Visual Studio Power Tools (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace). Install the tools relevant to your Visual Studio version and once they are installed, from the Visual Studio select Tools > Process Editor > Work Item Types > Open WIT From Server.

Here, connect to your TFS on-prem and select the Entity one-by-one as shown by the OpsHub Utility for having the mismatch. And delete the custom fields in question and save.

Click on Re-Validate in the OpsHub Utility. It should pass, if all the mismatched as shown before were taken care of through the above process.

Now, in case you want to destory the field you can use the `witadmin deletefield /collection:http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /m:field-reference_name` command.